# Proof in logic that $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ is the same as $ (\lnot P \lor Q) \land (\lnot Q \lor P)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How is it possible to prove that  $P \Leftrightarrow Q$ is the same as $ (\lnot P \lor Q) \land (\lnot Q \lor P)$ using logic laws?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align} p \iff q & \equiv (p \rightarrow q) \land (q\rightarrow p)\\ \\ 
& \equiv (\lnot p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor p)\end{align}$$

The first step is definitional. In the second step, I use, twice, the fact that $$a \rightarrow b \equiv \lnot a \lor b$$

Comment: I don't think that $$a \rightarrow b \iff \lnot a \lor b$$ is true by definition?

http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/symbolic_logic.html#switcheroo

I think one must prove that via truth tables.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Applications

Comment: Note, what I said was "definitional" is the fact that $p \iff q \equiv (p\implies q)\land (q \implies p)$.

Comment: does $\equiv$ not mean equal by definition?

Comment: Equivalent $\equiv$ means logical equivalence. It can be understood to mean that each side evaluates to the same truth value, and can be used instead of $\iff$. No matter what $a, b$ are, we know that $a \rightarrow b$ is true if and only if $\lnot a\lor b$ is true.

Answer (score 1):

Use truth tables to prove that

(!p OR q) <-> p -> q

and

(!q OR p) <-> q -> p.

Recall that p -> q is defined as such:

p q p -> q

T T      T

T F      F

F T      T

F F      T

So prove that ~p or q is equivalent to the above

Hmm...is p <-> equivalent to (p -> q) and (q -> p) by definition?

If so, QED.

If not, ...